# Is there any way to modify a value from 2 scripts in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to change the value of sensor_value from two python scripts test1.py :

```
from time import sleep 

class Sensor_value:
    def __init__(self):
        self.sensor_value = 1
    
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.sensor_value)

    def change(self, val):
        assert isinstance(val, int)
        self.sensor_value = val

sensor_value = Sensor_value()

while True :
    sensor_value.change(sensor_value.sensor_value - 1)
    sleep(2)
    print("value = {} from test 1".format(sensor_value))
```

and test2.py

```
from test1 import sensor_value
from time import sleep 

while True :
    sensor_value.change(sensor_value.sensor_value + 1)
    sleep(3)
    print("value = {} from test 2".format(sensor_value))
```

when I run the test2.py , the code stucks in the test1.py while loop, and never enter the test2.py while loop

here is the output :

```
$ python test2.py
value = 0 from test 1
value = -1 from test 1
value = -2 from test 1
value = -3 from test 1
```

can anyone help me please

Comment: You have a *single python process*. In tests2.py, you use `from test1 import sensor_value` runs *everything in `sensor_value`*, which includes an infinite loop, so nothing ever gets executed after `from test1 import sensor_value`. You are going to need some form of concurrency. Maybe start reading [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html) if you want everything in a single process. As an alternative, you can create mutiple processes, but then handling shared state becomes tricky (that's always tricky in concurrency).

Comment: if you want to run two `while` loops at the same time then you will have to use `threading`, `multiprocessing` or other method to run two processes ata the same time. But I would rather recreate code with only one `while` loop and `sleep(1)` and I would use some variable(s) to control if I have to run `sensor_value - 1` or `sensor_value + 1` or both in current loop.

Answer (score 0):

You have to modify your test1.py script, have to add the while loop under an if statement to check whether `__name__ == "__main__"`.

What happens is, Whenever you import the test1 module, the interpreter execute the test1 module.

such as if you add a print statement in the test1 module, during the importing of the test1 module, it will execute all the statement of test1 module.

In this case While running test2 script, the interpreter gets stuck at the first line of the test2 module executing The while loop of the test1 module.

```
from test1 import sensor_value
```

But, if you modify your test1 code like below:

```
from time import sleep 

class Sensor_value:
    def __init__(self):
        self.sensor_value = 1
    
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.sensor_value)

    def change(self, val):
        assert isinstance(val, int)
        self.sensor_value = val

sensor_value = Sensor_value()
if __name__=='__main__': ### putting while loop under if statement.
    
    while True :
        sensor_value.change(sensor_value.sensor_value - 1)
        sleep(2)
        print("value = {} from test 1".format(sensor_value))
```

Here, it will first check if the module is the main module else if the module imported from another module, the if statement will fail and it will ignore while loop of test1 module.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use `threading` or `multiprocessing` or other method to run two scripts at the same time but it would need more changes and maybe use `queue` to send values from one proccess to another. Shortly: it can be complicated when two functions/script what to access the same variable.

And this is why I would prefer to rewrite second `while True` loop to run all code in one loop.

In first script I would use `if __name__ == '__main__':` so I would run its loop when it runs directly but not when it is imported to another script.

**test1.py**

```
from time import sleep 

class Sensor_value:
    def __init__(self):
        self.sensor_value = 1
    
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.sensor_value)

    def change(self, val):
        assert isinstance(val, int)
        self.sensor_value = val

sensor_value = Sensor_value()

if __name__ == '__main__': # don't run when imported to other script
    while True:
        sensor_value.change(sensor_value.sensor_value - 1)
        sleep(2)
        print("value = {} from test 1".format(sensor_value))
```

And then in seconds script I would use `sleep(1)` and I would count seconds to check which part to execute.

**test2.py**

```
from test1 import sensor_value
from time import sleep 

seconds = 0

while True:

    if seconds % 2 == 0: # every 2 seconds
        sensor_value.change(sensor_value.sensor_value - 1)
        print("value = {} from test 1".format(sensor_value))

    if seconds % 3 == 0: # every 3 seconds
        sensor_value.change(sensor_value.sensor_value + 1)
        print("value = {} from test 2".format(sensor_value))

    sleep(1)  # it needs to sleep only 1 second

    seconds += 1
```

---

With threads I would put code in functions to run them later with `Thread()`

**test1.py**

```
from time import sleep 

class Sensor_value:
    def __init__(self):
        self.sensor_value = 1
    
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.sensor_value)

    def change(self, val):
        assert isinstance(val, int)
        self.sensor_value = val

sensor_value = Sensor_value()

def run_test1():
    while True:
        sensor_value.change(sensor_value.sensor_value - 1)
        sleep(2)
        print("value = {} from test 1".format(sensor_value))

if __name__ == '__main__': # don't run when imported to other script
    run_test1()
```

And start both threads in second script

**test2.py**

```
from test1 import sensor_value, run_test1
from time import sleep 
import threading

def run_test2():
    while True:
        sensor_value.change(sensor_value.sensor_value + 1)
        sleep(3)
        print("value = {} from test 3".format(sensor_value))


# create threads - `target` needs only function name without `()`
t1 = threading.Thread(target=run_test1)  # Thread(target=run_test1, args=(arg1,arg2))
t2 = threading.Thread(target=run_test1)

# start threads
t1.start()
t2.start()

# ... other code ...

# wait for the end of threads
t1.join()
t2.join()
```

But sometimes `threads` may have problem with correct updating the same variable and it may need some extra code to lock access to variable or use `queue` to send value to main thread which will update it.